# Wordpress Breadcrumb Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to insert "Blog" into the breadcrumb where blog posts are being viewed.

I tried this with Javascript/Jquery by trying to see if "blog" is in the url, if so, then find & replace. Example that I used:

JS

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("blog") > -1) { 
   $('#crumbs > a:first-of-type').replaceWith('<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a><a href="#">Blog</a>')
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="crumbs">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a>
    <a href="#/blog/category/uncategorized">Uncategorized</a>  <span class="current">Hello world!</span>
</div>
```

URL(domain replaced with #):

https://#/blog/uncategorized/hello-world

Although this doesn't seem to work without error. Rather, nothing has changed and there is no error in the Google Chrome console.

**UPDATE:**

I took the code out of the script.js file and placed it at the bottom of the footer like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("blog") > -1) {
            $('#crumbs').replaceWith('<a href="https://xarcell-studios.swagger.vip"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a><a href="#">Blog</a>')
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now I get the error in chrome console: $ is not a function.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: As it says, there is no error. I even tried just doing #crumbs, still didn't work. I assure you though, "Blog" is in the url.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your last sentence. So you mean, there is no explicit error, it just doesn't work?

Comment: Show us the html structure of `#crumbs`. My bet is the `<a>` aren't direct children as per your selector

Comment: I added the HTML, only changed the links.

Comment: Updated post with new information.